# Пунктуация при прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация

Мне нужно в своей группе процитировать немецкого лыжника Петера Шликенридера. И я сомневаюсь в правильности пунктуации в одном предложении. (На самом деле я вообще не уверен, что конструкции в кавычках являются прямой речтью.)

Приведу это предложение из книги Петера Шликенридера "Лыжный спорт" (перевод с немецкого Нины Бурмистровой):

Хваля ребёнка, лучше говорить: "Как далеко ты убежал!", а не "Какой ты быстрый!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Хваля ребёнка, лучше говорить "Как далеко ты убежал!", а не "Какой ты быстрый!"**

В этом случае дословные выказывания являются однородными дополнениями, связанными союзом *а не*. Двоеточие не ставится.

Примечание. Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но перед ними двоеточие не ставится, например: Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Гоголь); Он вспомнил пословицу «Не плюй в колодец…» и отошёл в сторону; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание. Источник: rosental-book.ru/punct_xxxi.html.

Comment: Чем оправдать (как объяснить) прописные внутри предложения?

Comment: Авторский выбор  (короткие реплики пишутся со строчной буквы, а более распространенные высказывания -  с прописной http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxxi.html   Примечание. Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но перед ними двоеточие не ставится, например: Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Гоголь); Он вспомнил пословицу «Не плюй в колодец…» и отошёл в сторону; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.Источник: http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxxi.html